# Criar uma query com agrupamento por mês

Tags: php, query, conversão

Eu tenho um campo no meu banco de dados (dt_nf) que é tipo DATE. Eu gostaria de fazer uma query que agrupasse não pela data, mas sim pelo mês e ano, mas não estou conseguindo. Meu código está assim:

```
SELECT 
Sum(sjy_vendas.qtv) AS qt, 
Sum(sjy_vendas.rprd) AS rec, 
Sum(rprd-tprd-vlr_compra) AS lucro
FROM sjy_type 
INNER JOIN sjy_empresas 
INNER JOIN sjy_vendas ON sjy_empresas.id_empresa = sjy_vendas.empresa
AND sjy_type.id_tipo = sjy_vendas.tipo
WHERE sjy_type.dep='1' 
AND sjy_empresas.grupo='$grupo' 
AND sjy_vendas.dt_nf BETWEEN '$inicio' AND '$final'
AND sjy_vendas.empresa LIKE '$emp'
GROUP BY MONTH(sjy_vendas.dt_nf) AS dt_nf
ORDER BY sjy_vendas.dt_nf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

existe duas formas de se fazer segue o ex:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(sjy_vendas.dt_nf,'%Y-%m')
```

ou então vc faz um extract do mes e ano do campo da data assim

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM sjy_vendas.dt_nf) mesano 
    FROM ...
```

e o group by vai ficar

```
GROUP BY mesano
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia.
Parece-me que se pretende agrupar pelas duas variaveis deve te-las no *group by* e te-las como coluna no *select*, pode ser algo como:

```
SELECT 
Sum(sjy_vendas.qtv) AS qt, 
Sum(sjy_vendas.rprd) AS rec, 
Sum(rprd-tprd-vlr_compra) AS lucro
concat(MONTH(sjy_vendas.dt_nf) , '/',YEAR(sjy_vendas.dt_nf)) as mesAno
...
GROUP BY concat(MONTH(sjy_vendas.dt_nf) , '/',YEAR(sjy_vendas.dt_nf))
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Ana, mas ainda não funcionou. Está dando o seguinte erro:    "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\n_kurma\pages\head.php on line 456"

Comment: esse erro não me parece relacionado com a query, experimentaste a query fora do php e não funciona? o que dizia é que tens de ter pelo menos o campo pelo qual queres agrupar no select.